# WordPress theme folder name showing in Google Analytics page paths

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I just noticed that the WordPress theme folder name is showing in some of the page paths of my reports, and was wondering if anyone had experienced this before.

For example when I view Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages, it shows a version of the page with the theme folder name visible and one without -

```
/theme_folder/news/article_name/
/news/article_name/
```

The URL's containing the theme folder should lead to a 404 error as that page doesn't actually exist; however the Average Time on Page indicate that the user spent around 2 minutes on the page, so they must have been served the page and read through the article.

Is this simply something to do with how WordPress generates the pages dynamically?
Is there anyway to prevent this, as it's dividing the stats for what are essentially the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your WordPress theme contains a 404 template file, then when a vistor sees that page, there's a good chance the tracking snippet is included in that template and therefore Google Analytics is tracking it.

You can confirm by going to that page and checking the network tab in your browser and seeing if anything is being sent to `www.google-analytics.com/collect`.

You can also go to the Behavior > Behavior Flow report to see how the user got there, but keep in mind they could have just manually typed that address into the address bar because it's a common folder in WordPress. To put that another way, lets say you discover they were on `/news/article_name/` before going to `/theme_folder/news/article_name/`. That doesn't necessarily mean there's actually a link to it from that page.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was absentmindedly thinking the 404 template filename would show in Analytics, but reading your answer reminded me that WordPress doesn't work that way.

The tracking code is included in my 404 template, so that explains the page views containing the theme folder being captured.I'm not sure how likely it is that someone would enter it directly as they won't know the name of the theme folder.

But I'll check the Behaviour Flow report to see if it gives any clues to dead links I might have left in my template files.

Thanks for your help, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: I just checked the Behaviour Flow, and noticed one of the Landing Page paths contained the theme folder name. So I thought I'd check the Acquisition Source for that landing, and realised it was coming from localhost. 

So what I thought was the theme folder name is actually the subdirectory inside my MAMP htdocs folder.

It seems the PHP logic I've written to exclude the tracking code while I developing locally isn't working all the time. But at least I have something solid to pursue.

Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction, you've been an excellent rubber duck. =P

Comment: No problem. If this answer helped you, then you should upvote it and/or mark it as accepted so others can benefit.